# Send app invite to friend

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I want to use facebook sdk (the newest one, 3.5) to send a request to a friend to try out my app. I have got it to work using the code below but no notification is sent to the user. It only shows the request when they go to the "apps" section within facebook. And to make things worse, it seems to only show up in the "apps" section if they go through the desktop site and not the native iOS facebook app.

Can anyone tell me what additional code needs to be added in order for the users to receive the notification inviting them to my app? Thanks!

**CODE**

```
 [FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
 message:@"Check out this new app!"
 title:@"Amazing new app!"
 parameters:nil
 handler:nil];
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is exactly whan an app request is. I don't think facebook creates notifications for these anymore (unless there's a specific preference for this, in which case the user can define that he wants to be notified)

Comment: @Stavash Thanks for the reply. I guess that makes sense but what about being able to see the request from your mobile device (iPhone in this case) in the "apps" section? Wouldn't it make sense that they would be able to see from a mobile device since the customer base are mobile users?

Comment: Have you tried this? + presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:message:title:parameters:handler:friendCache:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem but believe that the answer is as follow.
If you ONLY uses Facebook for iOS and not have a canvas app. It does downprioritize the notifications to only be in applicationcenter. However if you do have Facebook on iOS you will recieve the notification on the normal spot (the globe icon).

If you do have a canvas app as well the notification will be upprioritized on desktop (as it is on desktop you use the canvas) and will be visible in notifications.

I'm just looking for any facebook-source to confirm this but this is what it looks like when I try it out.

EDIT
Solution is confirmed. When I have an Facebook App (canvas) the notification is sent to notifications on desktop. If I don't, it is sent to applicationcenter.